# How to send text chunks in stream from spring rest controller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I would like to send data in chunks as and when it is ready from spring controller.

```
 @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home(){
         while(i=0;i<10;i++){
          //send numbers from 0 to 10 in chunks as http response
          //code to send this number as response
          Thread.sleep(50000);
        }
                }
```

How to achive this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring MVC can provide a servlet response object, which you can then write to.  E.g. :

```
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public void home(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            writer.println(i);
            writer.flush();
            Thread.sleep(50000);
        }
    }
```

Comment: To test that this works, the response should include the header, `transfer-encoding: chunked`, and should _not_ include a `content-length` header.

Comment: @jaco0646 are you perhaps aware of how to include this header in the response?

Comment: @Jason, if this is working, Spring will add the header `transfer-encoding: chunked` instead of a `content-length` header.